# Send entire div content to email in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this div

```
<div class="printclass" #print style="display:none">
  <div>
    <h1> <h1>
    <div *ngFor..>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this content in html component and I want to access it in the ts file as a string and then pass it to api.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some id to this div:

```
<div id="emailContent" class="printclass" #print style="display:none">
<div>
<h1> <h1>
<div *ngFor..>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and in ts you can get its html as string by:

```
document.getElementById("emailContent").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Component implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('print', { static: true }) private print: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.print.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
```

I'm unsure if it is everything you wanted, but it should be enough to get innerHTML as a string.